# Different Source Files For Different Compile Options in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, coding-style, standards

Is there a `Standard(ish)` or a way todo this is Visual Studio to dealing with different source files for different compile options?

Right now I have an OpenGL and DirectX framework and I am in the process of merging them together. Currently how I'm differentating them is by included in a `#if defined` in the source file

```
// GraphicsGL.hpp
#include <platform.hpp>

#if defined(USE_GL)
// code
#endif
```

and

```
// GraphicsDX.cpp
#include <platform.hpp>

#if defined(USE_DX)
// code
#endif
```

I don't want to go down the path of two different projects, there is more stuff that isn't dependent on platform than is.

Comment: your current solution is not that bad.. You can have a configration called Release_OpenGL defining USE_GL and Release_Dx defining USE_DX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you factor out the platform dependent code into its own library and you build different versions of it. The actual project would have separate build configurations that would use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude files from build and you can specify preprocessor symbols definition per file; just right click the file then properties in the solution explorer